# How can I combine results of queries from two different classes in parse.com android?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have two classes each having a user reference of the ParseUser class and a ParseGeoPoint object. I had to do this since parse does not allow two ParseGeoPoint objects with the same key. Now i want to combine the results of both the queries into a ParseQueryAdapter and set a listview to it. My concerns are :

1) How can i combine the results of the queries.

```
ParseQuery<Source> srclist = Source.getQuery();
srclist.include("user");
srclist.whereNear("src", src);

ParseQuery<Destination> destlist = Destination.getQuery();
destlist.include("user");
destlist.whereEqualTo("dest", dest);

//Source and Destination are the two classes which have one ParseGeoPoint and a user reference respectively.
```

2) How can i populate a listview with the combined results?

This is what i'm doing for combining, is it right?

```
Location myLoc =currentLocation;
ParseGeoPoint mySrc=geoPointFromLocation(myLoc);
srclist=Source.getQuery();
srclist.include("user");
srclist.whereWithinKilometers("src", mySrc, 5.0);
destlist = Destination.getQuery();
destlist.include("user");
destlist.whereNear("dest", myDest);
destlist.whereMatchesQuery("user", srclist);
ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseUser> factory= new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseUser>(){
@Override
public ParseQuery<ParseUser> create() {
user = ParseUser.getQuery();
user.whereMatchesQuery("user", destlist);
user.setLimit(MAX_SEARCH_RESULTS);
return user;
}
};
```

It apparently does not return any result as my list view is still empty!!

Comment: Did this solution work for you? Do you need more help?

Comment: @VonSchnauzer Sorry, but that is not what i'm looking for!!

Comment: Since you haven't got much answers, perhaps you could rephrase it? And just saying it's not what you are looking for is not going to get us any closer to an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

1) combine the by creating a holder: an object with three fields: (or you can make them private with setters/getters)

```
public class WhereAbouts{

    public String user;
    public Source src;
    public Destination dest;
}
```

Then add this to a list in your callback from ParseQuery

```
List<WhereAbouts> list = new ArrayList<WhereAbouts>();
list.add(whereAbouts);
```

2) In your getView() in your Adapter you get the WhereAbouts object and set each textfield:

```
getView(...){
  ....
  WhereAbouts w = getItem(position);
  myTextField.setText(w.user); 
  //etc...
}
```

Check google/SO for Listview and adapters if you don't know about those.

Comment: I have added a piece of code of what i'm trying to achieve.